# Clarification in usage of Regular Expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am new to Regex. Please correct me where am doing wrong in below code.
Also Please suggest some nice books/tutorials in Java-Regex.

```
public class regexx {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String s = "Bug 2742";
    if("^Bug [0-9]*".matches(s)){
        System.out.println("eq");
    }else {
        System.out.println("nq");
    }
}
}
```

Am expecting "eq" as output.But the match is returning false.

Comment: Oracle official tutorial : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: Off topic: Java coding conventions recommend [PascalCase](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PascalCase) for class names. Meaning the first letter is a capital letter hence: `regexx` would be `Regexx`. Aside from constants (which should be all caps) all variables and methods should be camelCase. Following these standard conventions allows other Java programmers to easily understand what you code does.

Comment: @izuriel I like that constructive comment. :)

Comment: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!")

Answer (score 3):

The regex should be the argument 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm

```
s.matches ("^Bug [0-9]*")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean matches(String regex)
```

[String#matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)  takes regex as parameter,Not the `string` which you are doing operation.

You are doing in the reverse while applying `regex`

For Clarification, I separated that line.

Try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s = "Bug 2742";
        boolean matches = s.matches("^Bug [0-9]*");
        if(matches){
            System.out.println("eq");
        }else {
            System.out.println("nq");
        }
    }
```